# Cucumber does not recognize my string parameter in Java after adding examples value

Tags: java, cucumber

After adding examples value, Undefined step reference problem in using cucumber in java . Before adding examples value it recognize.

**Feature** :

```
...
And a person <name>
```

**Example :**

```
|name|

|"firs" |
```

**TestStep** :

```
@And("^a person name(.*)$")
public void aPersonName(String name) {
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding example values it should be changed as following:

```
@And("^a person (.*)$")
```

means "name" should be removed.